# Tengo + que + infinitive vs tengo infinitive

Tags: gramática

What is the difference between tengo que and an infinitive (tengo que limpiar “I have to clean”) and just tengo limpiar…(I have + to clean)?
They both translate to the same English sentence.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure _tener limpiar_ is grammatical? The other one is fine.

Comment: tengo que hacer x is to have to do something. tengo infinitive is not grammatical in Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

Although the translation of *have* is **tener**, in this particular case, the meaning of the word is important in Spanish. Here it has the meaning of **need** or **must**. When **tener** is used as in *need* you always need to add **que** to introduce the next statement.

- **Tengo que** limpiar.  (I need to clean.)
- **Tendré que** hacerlo yo mismo.  (I will need to do it myself.)
- **Tengo que** preguntarte algo. (I need to ask you something.)

You can find the complete definition [here](https://dle.rae.es/tener).

The construction verb + infinitive is fine but you must change the verb

- Debo limpiar
- Necesitaré hacerlo yo mismo
- Quiero preguntarte algo